# Where does 4N and 3N goes in this diagram?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

Two forces of 3 N and 4 N are acting at a point such that the angle between them is 60 degrees. Find the resultant force.

I successfully draw diagram for above sentence:

[image]

But I am confused which one should be in base: 4N or 3N?

Comment: In the diagram you've drawn, the angle between those two forces is not 60°; but 120°.

Comment: Your diagram isn't very useful. Draw a triangle with two sides having length 3 & 4, with the angle between those sides being 60°. The other side is the resultant.

Answer (score 2):

These vector addition diagrams are equivalent to one another and it does not matter whether you give the direction of the resultant force $R$ relative to the $3\,\rm N$ force, $\theta$, or the $4\,\rm N$ force, $\phi$.

[image]